# Не выводятся данные из MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть запрос на вывод данных, который хорошо себя отрабатывает в phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT `android_php_post`.name,  `clients`.orgazniz,  `clients`.ardrees, `grafidotpis`.datapos, `grafidotpis`.timepos, `grafidotpis`.timezakr, `kod_vizova`.vid,`grafidotpis`.message
FROM `android_php_post` , `grafidotpis` , `clients` , `kod_vizova`
WHERE `android_php_post`.age = `grafidotpis`.idsotr
AND `clients`.idadrs = `grafidotpis`.idadresorg
AND `grafidotpis`.idviezd
AND `grafidotpis`.datapos
AND `grafidotpis`.timepos
AND `grafidotpis`.timezakr
AND `grafidotpis`.idviezd = `kod_vizova`.cod
ORDER BY newid DESC
```

Пытаюсь вывести все этот же запрос в PHP таблицу

```
$sql = "SELECT `android_php_post`.name,  `clients`.orgazniz,  `clients`.ardrees, `grafidotpis`.datapos, `grafidotpis`.timepos, `grafidotpis`.timezakr, `kod_vizova`.vid,`grafidotpis`.message
FROM `android_php_post` , `grafidotpis` , `clients` , `kod_vizova`
WHERE `android_php_post`.age = `grafidotpis`.idsotr
AND `clients`.idadrs = `grafidotpis`.idadresorg
AND `grafidotpis`.idviezd
AND `grafidotpis`.datapos
AND `grafidotpis`.timepos
AND `grafidotpis`.timezakr
AND `grafidotpis`.idviezd = `kod_vizova`.cod
ORDER BY newid DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo
 '</br><table class="live_filter"  >
      <tr>
 <td class="title" style="width:100px;" align="center"> Сотрудник </td>
        <td style="width:70px;" align="center"> Контрагент </td>
         <td style="width:70px;" align="center"> Адрес </td>
        <td style="width:10px;" align="center"> Вид посещения </td>
        <td style="width:10px;" align="center"> Статус посещения  </td>
        <td style="width:10px;" align="center"> Время/Дата посещения </td>
        <td style="width:20px;" align="center"> Сообщение </td>
        <td style="width:20px;" align="center"> Сообщение </td>
      </tr>';
      echo '
        <tr>
        <td class="title" style="width:70px; padding-left:10px;" >'.$row['name'].'</td>
        <td style="width:70px; padding-left:10px;" >'. $row['orgazniz'].'</td>
         <td style="width:70px; padding-left:10px;" >'. $row['ardrees'].'</td>
        <td style="width:20px;" align="center">'. $row['datapos'].'</td>
        <td style="width:20px; align="center">'. $row['timepos'].'</td>
        <td style="width:10px;" align="center">'. $row['timezakr'].'</td>
        <td style="width:20px; ">'. $row['vid'].'</td>
        <td style="width:20px; ">'. $row['message'].'</td>
              </tr>';
             echo '</table>'; 
  }
 } else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
$conn->close();
```

Но, вместо вывода результата, получается задваение название столбцов, но опять же, что удивительно, задваевается ровно столько же, сколько строк выведет запрос из phpmyadmin

Пример задвоения:

```
Сотрудник   Контрагент  Адрес   Вид посещения   Статус посещения    Время/Дата посещения    Сообщение   Сообщение           
Сотрудник   Контрагент  Адрес   Вид посещения   Статус посещения    Время/Дата посещения    Сообщение   Сообщение
```

Comment: Сделайте echo var_dump($row) или запустите отладку, посмотрите что в этой переменной после запроса к fetch_assoc. Неужели не знаете как выяснить что не так, когда известно то что должно быть?

Comment: спасибо большое, что указали куда смотреть, проблема решилась этой строчкой  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {